Sharing PowerBI app to Customer Environment - (no Azure AD)
I have a power bi app created from my PowerBI tenant. Everytime I give access of this app to an external user (Customer), powerBI creates and Azure AD guest account for them and creates a new Power BI tenant for them.
Question:

If they already have a license in their tenant, can they still use the app i shared from this new tenant powerbi created.

How can i share in a way, that this app is visible in their own tenant.


I have pro license, and customer also have pro license.
I tried adding external user in workspace, but it does not allow external organisation to add in workspace. Then I tried sharing the app, then I was expecting them to see the app in their own tenant but instead Azure AD created a guest account and a new Power BI tenant for them.

You have hit a limitation of how items are shared.

If they already have a license in their tenant, can they still use
the app i shared from this new tenant powerbi created.

That is correct, as they have their own PBI Pro license, they can be an AAD External user and see the report. If they don't have a license, you would have to allocate one to them. They will have to log into PBI Service, with your tenant id added to the url
https://app.powerbi.com/home?ctid=<host's tenant id (ctid)>
See here for a detailed answer:
How to access power BI Service in multi tenant scenario

How can i share in a way, that this app is visible in their own
tenant.

You can't, you would have to re-deploy your app in their tenant
